# How to plot pixels instead of points in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of points {(x1,y1),(x2,y2),....,(xn,yn)} whit x_i and y_i integers for all i. I wish to plot them, but instead of points I'd like them to be square pixels with center in the point and side length 1, starting 1/2 to the left of the point and ending 1/2 to the right...For example, with the point (1,1) should be: [image: point (1,1)]

Comment: Do you want pixels or squares? Bear in mind that matplotlib can output graphics in a form that has no concept of pixels - like SVG - so you might have to make some compromises if it's really single pixels you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is [imshow](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html).
A small example, where each square is a pixel (a very small image of 3x3). The color is given by the data values of the array. If data has only 0 and 1, it will be 2 colors only.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random(size=(3, 3))

plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.0, 2.5, 1), np.arange(0.5, 2, 0.5))
plt.yticks(np.arange(2, -0.5, -1), np.arange(0.5, 2, 0.5))
```

[image: imshow example]

Notice the `interpolation='nearest'` that causes it does not interpolate the points, but rather shows us squares.

Comment: Thanks mate, but how do I choose color? In particular I want my set of points to be all of white color, while the rest being black(like the bottom of the picture)

Comment: The color is given by the `data` values of the array. If data has only 0 and 1, it will be 2 colors only (if you choose a correct cmap, it will be black and white). I do not understand what you want.